# Nullpointer Exception While loading drawable xml for EditText background

Tags: android, background, android-edittext, drawable

I am using Drawable xml for EditText background. But it gives null pointer exception.
i am using the following :

**my layout xml :**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="#000000" >


    <EditText android:id="@+id/edtbox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
       android:inputType="number"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:background="@drawable/edtbackground"
       />

     <EditText android:id="@+id/edtbox1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtbox"
        android:inputType="number"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**edtbackground.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item>
      <shape android:shape="line" android:thickness="1dp">
      <solid android:color="#000000" />
      </shape>
  </item>

  <!-- main color -->
  <item android:bottom="1.5dp"
      android:left="1.5dp"
      android:right="1.5dp">
      <shape >
          <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
      </shape>
  </item>

  <!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars -->
  <item android:bottom="2sp">
      <shape >
          <solid android:color="#000000" />
      </shape>
  </item>

  <Item   android:state_window_focused = "false">
       <shape >
          <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
      </shape>
  </Item>  
  <Item   android:state_focused = "true" >  
       <shape >
          <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
      </shape>
      </Item>


  </layer-list>
```

**Exception :**

```
    09-09 11:51:27.711: E/AndroidRuntime(30677): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 11:51:27.711: E/AndroidRuntime(30677): 
java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 11:51:27.711: 
E/AndroidRuntime(30677):    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.setupModifiers(GLES20Canvas.java:1413)
09-09 11:51:27.711: 
E/AndroidRuntime(30677):    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawLines(GLES20Canvas.java:994)
09-09 11:51:27.711: 
E/AndroidRuntime(30677):    at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawLines(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:161)
09-09 11:51:27.711: 
E/AndroidRuntime(30677):    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawLine(GLES20Canvas.java:984)
09-09 11:51:27.711: 
E/AndroidRuntime(30677):    at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawLine(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:155)
09-09 11:51:27.711: 
E/AndroidRuntime(30677):    at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.draw(GradientDrawable.java:537)
09-09 11:51:27.711: 
E/AndroidRuntime(30677):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.draw(LayerDrawable.java:345)
```

so, please guide me what mistake i did.

Comment: is the filename `drawable.xml` ? shouldn't it be `edtbackground.xml` ?

Comment: change `drawable.xml` name.

Comment: no, it is already edtbackground.xml

Comment: Activity.java:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
}

Comment: Is this the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Item android:state_window_focused = "false">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</Item>  
<Item android:state_focused = "true" >  
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    </shape>
</Item>
```

`Item` is not the correct token. Change these to `item`, with a lowercase `i`.

**ASIDE**

Even with the change above, your drawable XML probably will not behave the way you expect it to. In particular:

- The attributes `android:bottom`, `android:left`, and `android:right` are not applicable to `<item>` elements inside of a `<layer-list>`. If these are meant to be padding, then you need to use a `<padding>` element inside of a `<shape>` element. If these are meant to be insets, you need to use an `<inset>` element inside the `<item>` element.
- The attributes `android:state_window_focused` and `android:state_focused` are not applicable to `<item>` elements inside of a `<layer-list>`. They are used on `item` elements inside a `selector` element.

Please refer to [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) and check that the attributes you use are being applied to the appropriate elements. There are many examples on this page. I don't know what happens when inapplicable attributes are used on these elements; I would assume they are ignored, but you never know.

Comment: i changed, but still it gives same exception.